# Vim regex find/replace to turn php array notation into object notation

Tags: regex, vim

In a PHP file, I'm trying to convert all array notation into object notation.  In other words, I'm trying to convert all occurrences of this:

$thing['key']

into:

$thing->key

I thought this was a simple regex problem.  I am searching for this pattern:

```
\$thing\['(.*?)'\]
```

And replacing with this:

```
$thing->\1
```

It works correctly in Text Wrangler, but doesn't work in VIM.  This is the full command I'm trying to run:

```
:s/\$thing\['(.*?)'\]/$thing->\1/g
```

The error I get is:

```
E486: Pattern not found: \$thing\['(.*?)'\]
```

I also tried the command with escaped parenthesis around the group:

```
:s/\$thing\['\(.*?\)'\]/$thing->\1/g
```

But I get the same error.  Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must escape parentheses to do grouping and [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) uses `.\{-}` expression to do a non-greedy match. It would be like:

```
:s/\$thing\['\(.\{-}\)'\]/$thing->\1/g
```

Comment: Thank Birei.  That worked.  I needed to use :%s instead of :s in order to replace the whole file.

Comment: if you prepend using `%`, it matches every line of your current document

Comment: (...which is almost always what you need if you're composing a complex regex.  If you're only interested in changing a single line you'll normally just do it by hand unless the regex is dead simple.)

Answer (score 2):

as an alternative you can also do:

```
qq           ; save macro in register q
/$thing<CR>  ; look for next $thing
"adi'        ; remove everything between quotes on current line and place it in register a 
; result: $thing[''_]
l            ; move to next character on right
; result: $thing['']_
d%           ; remove everything up to matching bracket
; result: $thing
i-><ESC>
; result: $thing->
"ap          ; paste from register a
; result: $thing->key
q            ; end macro
```

and remove the next one using the macro:

```
@q
```

and the following one repeating the macro:

```
@@
```

and to repeat the macro 42 times:

```
42@@
```

Comment: yeah, I do like vimgolf ;-)

Answer (score 0):

See [Grouping and backreferences](http://vimregex.com/#backreferences), paranthesis has to be escaped.
The below works for me

```
:s/\$thing\['\(.*\)'\]/$thing->\1/g
```